# Are there any applications of Quantum Mechanics to probability theory or financial maths?

Tags: probability-theory, finance, quantum-mechanics

I have no prior knowledge of quantum mechanics whatsoever, but I am aware that some of the theory (I believe on quantum states) is based on probability. I’m wondering if there are topics/notions in quantum mechanics that can be used to apply to scenarios/problems involving stochastic processes in applied scenarios, probability theory in general or financial mathematics?